# how to take value of 'while' to include array unique

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, explode, array-unique

table:

```
fungi  |  fruit  |  country

fungi-a       Aple, Orange, Grape,               Japan, America, China, Australia,

fungi-b       Aple, Watermelon, Grape,           Korea, America, China,

fungi-c       Aple, Watermelon, Orange,          Korea, Canada, China, America

fungi-d       Aple, Grape, Orange,               Japan, Canada,

include"config.php";

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `fruit` LIKE
'%aple%' AND `country` LIKE'%korea%'");

function asd(){

 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

 echo $row['country'];

 } } echo implode(',',array_unique(explode(',',asd())));
```

**value is:** Korea, America, China, Korea, Canada, China, Amerika

**but i want this value:** Korea, America, China, Canada,

i make array_unique explode but not worked,

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: You need to re-evaluate your code. You should begin by normalizing your database. This will alleviate the need to do any type of `array_unique` manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning any value at asd()

This should work:

```
function asd() {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `fruit` LIKE '%aple%' AND `country` LIKE'%korea%'");
    $countries = array();
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $countries = array_merge($countries, explode(',', $row['country']));
    }
    return array_unique($countries);
}
echo implode(',', asd());
```

This will put every 'country' record in the $countries array and return it.

You may also should take a look at OOP and PDO (PHP Data Objects) or MySQLi (MySQL improved).

Comment: this is because it's returning an array, try `var_dump(asd());`.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
include"config.php";

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `fruit` LIKE
'%aple%' AND `country` LIKE'%korea%'");

function asd(){

    $myarr = array();

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

      if (!in_array($row['country'], $myarr)) {
        $myarr[] = $row['country'];
      }

    }
    return $myarr;
} 

echo implode(",", asd());
```

Comment: your code minus `}` and `Array();` must be `array();` then I try and complete with that but not worked,,